# Suggest a rich text editor in asp.net mvc3 with option for page size setting,print preview & Page zoom

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Suggest a rich text editor in asp.net mvc3 with options

1)Page size setting(A4,letter etc).

2)supports page zooming in Print layout

3)Support multiple pages.

4)exported to PDF format.

5)Font Setting & Text formatting.

Does such an HTML editor exist? Can anyone guide me to one?

Our requirement show in the picture given below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Personally I never heard of such an editor. 
The solution I think is near your request is to use a combination of components from a Controls suite like [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/).

In these suites every component is greatly integrated with each others and you should be able to obtain what you need without much effort.